# Powershell - get-Itemproperty into array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am working on a powershell script to find all the Component registry keys, which have a Data Key under them of "00004109F100C0400000000000F01FEC".  The following powershell returns the results that I want, however I am expecting "$test" to be an array so I can loop through each value.  In the below code it is not and I can't figure out why.

```
$test = @()
$test = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\ | ForEach-Object { (Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath -Name "00004109F100C0400000000000F01FEC" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).PSPath }
```

How can I modify the above to get the results in $test to be an array of Component keys that I can loop though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works better:

```
$test = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\ |
 Where { $_.Property -eq "00004109F100C0400000000000F01FEC" } |
 select -ExpandProperty PSPath
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.  That is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: @mjolinor - why use `select -expandproperty pspath` when `% PSPath` outputs the same thing?

Comment: @keithHill - mostly habit developed from performance considerations. The select is faster than the foreach, although in this case the difference is probably too trivial to worry about.

Comment: @mjolinor Well there's performance faster and typing faster. For performance, the fastest is probably `(Get-ChildItem ... | Where ...).PSPath`.  But yeah, I definitely my habits WRT PowerShell as well - not all of them good.  :-)

Comment: I know. INHO, the worst is when tab-completion gets to be muscle memory, and you start trying to do it outside of Powershell.